# Which constructor am I calling?

Tags: java

I am novice. I have the next code and I do not know which constructor am I calling?

```
 ClassName object = getobjectInfo()
```

where the ClassName class has the next constructors

```
public ClassName(int a)
{
//whatever
}

public ClassName(double a)
{
//whatever
}

public ClassName(int a, double b, string c)
{
//whatever
}
```

What I understand is:

1. I create the object of class `ClassName`, calling any constructor. Which one?
2. Then I call the `getobjectInfo()` method.

Which constructor am I calling?

Comment: You're not calling any.

Comment: Get familiar with a debugger.

Comment: method `getobjectInfo()` is unknown to us.

Comment: `getobjectInfo()` might be calling a constructor, check there

Comment: Why not? Then how object is created? what am i doing?? hahah

Comment: `getobjectInfo()` returned the object, but when and where it was created - with which constructor - may vary.

Answer (score 1):

**We** don't know if you are calling an constructor. Consider the following code:

```
public ClassName getobject() {
    return null;
}
```

It clearly does not instantiate `ClassName` at all. As opposed to:

```
public ClassName getobject() {
    return new ClassName(1);  // Now you are calling a constructor.
}
```

But *we* don't know what your `getobject` method is doing.

Comment: Ok! yes my getobjectinfo() method is calling a constructor (the third one) but just after see, if some parameters of the object are null. So the constructor must be called before.

Comment: Nope. You can only call a constructor once; Java ensures this. Maybe use a debugger, such as the one built-in with eclipse (there is a manual, too)